# Visual Studio 2010 - Duplicate tables when using datasource wizard

Tags: visual-studio, duplicates, datasource, prefix, owner

I hope someone can help me, because I've seen a couple of problems like this one, without a concrete solution.

I developed a Solution in Visual Studio 2010, months ago.
Yesterday, I was doing maintenance and when trying to add new tables with the DataSource Wizard, the window showed me up, my database tables (without dbo. prefix, and unchecked), which I usually see, and also, below them, the same table list but with dbo. prefix and checked.

I don't know what would happen if I change everything to the dbo. prefix tables. May be source code should be changed also?

What I want is to have one single database table list; same as I had before.
Without dbo. prefix.

Comment: Anyone ever get an answer on this?